# Lightswitch SSO

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012, lightswitch-2013

My question is if I can setup multiple lightswitch applications to authenticate against a single ASP.NET website's authentication provider when using forms authentication, can I not just them up to authenticate against a lightswitch application instead?

I could have for example a lightswitch portal application (instead of ASP.NET website) that manages the users and sub-sites.

The question is then how do I setup one lightswitch application to authenticate users against another lightswitch application? End-to-End example please.

Answer (score 2):

LightSwitch is based on ASP.NET's authentication implementation so it's really not any different than having two plain ASP.NET apps sharing a membership data source for authentication.  You just need to configure their web.config files so that the ASP.NET membership/role/profile providers all share the same application name (which is used to partition data) between the two apps.  Michael Washington has a good article on this: http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/107/Integrating-LightSwitch-Into-An-ASPNET-Application-To-Provide-Single-Sign-On.aspx.